# Do not have select privilege for temporary table in db2 stored procedure

Tags: select, stored-procedures, db2, privileges, create-table

I am running a stored procedure in DB2 10.1 which creates a created global temporary table and it returns the following error message that seems to say that it cannot select from the temporary table that it has just created in the same stored procedure

> "USER" does not have the required authorization or privilege to
>   perform operation "SELECT" on object "MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE"..
>   SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.16.53

I have not encountered this problem with the other stored procedures and they create temp tables in the same way.  The user privileges are controlled by groups, but due to issues with the groups I have started to give privileges to the users directly.

I cannot grant select permissions to the temp table because its not yet created and not sure how to fix this situation.

Has anyone come across this problem before and if so how did you fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but that doesn't really look like a temp table (even though you have changed the schema name)... those always start with the schema `SESSION`. Is it possible that you're creating and dropping a "real" table?

Comment: It is a create global tempoary table that has been createdd in the schema instead of session.

Comment: My understanding is that "created" temp tables are declared once at the server level, and then can be re-used by multiple applications (even at the same time, but with different data), so your statement that you're creating it in the stored procedure doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If you want to declare it every time, then maybe you want ["declared" temporary tables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declareglobaltemptable.dita).

Comment: Do you think it might be useful to include the source code of the procedure you're asking us to debug?